# Python : Variable size problems with Pyscripter

Tags: python, performance, size, pyscripter

I am using Pyscripter to script and execute Python codes. I have a scenario where I'm population a tuple in a loop. And, at the end of the program I have 10 such variables with 1 Million elements in each. Pyscripter hangs when I try to call any variable after this.

Any tips how to overcome this? Are there any limitations on the size of variables in workspace? I have sufficient space in my disk to support the data.

Comment: What do you mean by "call any variable"? You don't call variables, you call functions. What are you actually trying to do? My guess is that PyScripter is working fine and it merely takes a long time to display a container with a million elements in it. To avoid this, don't try to display all million elements.

Comment: @kindall I have a variable, A with 1million elements. I am simply trying to get the output, `>> A[-1]` or `>> A[99999]`. Not just that. Even while typing, it hangs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are adding to a tuple in a loop, you might be better off starting with a list, then converting it to a tuple later:

```
mylist = []
for i in range(million):
    mylist.append(something)
mytup = tuple(mylist)
```

But if you're appending to something a million times, it's possible that your program just takes time to populate the tuple...